# Updating relation Model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, relationship, updating

I'm new to Laravel 5. I viewed the tutorial "Laravel 5 Fundamentals" and I have an issue.

**Article model**

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

**Category model**

```
public function article()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Article');
}
```

**ArticleController**

```
public function create()
{
    $categories = Category::lists('name', 'id');

    return view('admin.article.create', compact('categories'));
}

public function store(ArticleRequest $request)
{
    $article = new Article($request->all());
    $category = Category::find($request->input('categories'));
    $article->category()->associate($category);
    \Auth::user()->article()->save($article);

    return \Redirect::to('/admin/article');
}

public function edit(Article $article)
{
    $categories = Category::lists('name', 'id');

    return view('admin.article.edit', compact('article', 'categories'));
}

public function update(Article $article, ArticleRequest $request)
{
    $article->update($request->all());

    return redirect('admin/article');
}
```

How can I update the Article model and the related Category model?

Answer (score 0):

You can update like this: (original source:  http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#insert-update-delete)

```
public function update(Article $article, ArticleRequest $request)
{
    $newValues = $request->except('_method', '_token');
    foreach($newValues as $key => $value)
    {
         $article[$key] = $value;
    }
    $article->save();

    return redirect('admin/article');
}
```

or

```
public function update(Article $article, ArticleRequest $request)
{
    $article->title = $request->input('title');
    //all article's table columns = $request->input('corresponding_input_name')
    $article->save();

    return redirect('admin/article');
}
```

As sugguested by @patricus:

```
public function update(Article $article, ArticleRequest $request)
{
    $article->fill($request->all());
    $article->save();
    return redirect('admin/article');
}
```

Comment: I gen an error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_method' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `articles` (`_method`, `_token`, `title`, `slug`, `category_id`, `body`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (PATCH, ***, First article, first-article, 2, lorem ipsum 11, 2015-06-01 17:39:19, 2015-06-01 17:39:19))

Comment: exclude _method or _token like this: $request->except('_method', '_token'); I wrote a foreach expecting $request->all() contains all your table columns. Just grab from $request the columns you need and they need to have the same name.

Comment: @brlebtag You should use the `fill()` method on the model. This will take into account any `fillable` or `guarded` restrictions on the model, and also automatically ignores any parameters that start with an underscore (such as _token and _method).

Comment: @patricus thx I didn't know that. I have to take a look and read all Eloquent model's method.